# Java Beginner: Letting one class know that another has finished

Tags: java

I'm making a Java game that has a main class, a battle class, a monster class, a player class, etc... I have stats displayed on the main class frame. A button press creates a new battle frame, which also shows stats. After the battle, the stats are different (for example, the Player's health points are lower than they were before being hit by the monster). I need these changes in the stats to be reflected back on the main frame after the battle frame disappears.

What is the best way to tell the main class that the battle is finished and to refresh the stats? Code is below. It's a work in progress, obviously, and there are a few other irrelevant classes.

portion of main class that starts a battle (ie, creates a new battle object, which is a JFrame):

```
public class DarkWorld extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ...
    public DarkWorld()
    {
        ...
    public void createInfoLabel()
    {
        infoLabel.setText("<html>Player: " + DarkWorld.user.getPlayerName()
            + "<br>Health: " + DarkWorld.user.getHealth()
            + "<br>Attack Damage: " + DarkWorld.user.getAttackDamage()
            + "<br>Level: " + DarkWorld.user.getLevel()
            + "<br>Experience: " + DarkWorld.user.getExperience());
    }
    ...
        if(source == monsterButton)
        {

            BattleFrame battle = new BattleFrame();
            final int WIDTH = 700;
            final int HEIGHT = 500;
            battle.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            battle.setVisible(true);
        }
        ...
}
```

Portion of Battle class:

```
...


public class BattleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Monster newMonster = new Monster();
    ...
    public BattleFrame()
    ...
    public void displayStats()
    {
        monsterLabel.setText("<html>Type: " + newMonster.getMonsterName()
                + "<br>Health: " + newMonster.getHealth()
                + "<br>Attack: " + newMonster.getAttackName()
                + "<br>Attack Damage: " + newMonster.getAttackDamage());
        playerLabel.setText("<html>Player: " + DarkWorld.user.getPlayerName()
                + "<br>Health: " + DarkWorld.user.getHealth()
                + "<br>Attack Damage: " + DarkWorld.user.getAttackDamage()
                + "<br>Level: " + DarkWorld.user.getLevel()
                + "<br>Experience: " + DarkWorld.user.getExperience());
    }
    ...
            if(newMonster.getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                ...
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You killed the monster! You found a " + newItem.getItemName()
                        + ". It has been added to your inventory.");
                dispose();
            }
            if(DarkWorld.user.getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                //if player dies (health reaches zero), the game is over - need to make game end
                displayStats();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The monster killed you!");
                dispose();
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

EDIT: Tried to simplify the code here so it is more clear what I am asking.

Comment: I suspect this a matter of terminology, but ivaonic is right. Do you mean the `main` function? In that case the program ends when it finishes and there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. The main class is supposed to stick around the whole time, and call the battle class whenever the button is pressed.

Comment: @ivanovic Maybe being disposed by GC is what he means?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, the main class (called DarkWorld) calls a Battle when the button is pressed. After the battle, the battle frame is disposed. A new battle is created after the button is pressed again.

Comment: Boy that's a whole load of code. (Try and include in your questions simplified samples with only the code relevant to the problem you're facing.)

Comment: Thanks, millimoose. I trimmed down the code pieces a bit. :)

Comment: Looks like my question got a negative vote. Perhaps I'm overthinking this. All I really need to know is how to let another class, which holds a different frame than the one that is in focus, know to refresh. I thought maybe calling firstClass.validate() from the second class would refresh the first class, but didn't work. I'd appreciate any ideas on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just create a method in your main class:

```
public void updateStats() { /*update the stats*/ }
```

Then, in your Battle class, when the battle is done, you just call that method. Also, I think you might find it useful to implement the Singleton pattern in your project, since it sounds like there will only be one battle class at all times.

You might also want to put all of the battle logic into a class. The best programming advice I've ever gotten was to seperate logic from GUI.

Or, you might just want to ignore everything I've said since I'm only 13 and I program in C#, not Java.

Comment: Okay, so are you saying to call this method from within the main class to create a new battle object when a battle needs to be started, and then call this same method again from the battle class after the battle has finished?

Also, maybe I'm not fully understanding my own code. It seems to me that there are as many battle objects as there are battles started, a new one each time the button is pressed, but only one at a time. In other words, doesn't the dispose() method eliminate the battle object?

Comment: I understand your code much better now that you have simplified it.

Comment: Since there is only one battle class at a time, you can use the Singleton pattern to have access to that one battle class. The Singleton class would have a method called resetBattle() , which would be called whenever a battle ends.

Comment: I like this idea. But now I have a new issue. I have an updateStats() method in the main class:

`private static JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("");

...

public static void updateStats()
 {
  infoLabel.setText( /* stats updated */);
  validate();
 }`

I made the JLabel and the method static - otherwise I couldnt call them from the battle class. But I still can't call the method because the validate() method can't be in a static method. I need to have the validate() method inside a method in the main class that can be called from another class. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Make that method nonstatic. Add a DarkWorld field to the other classes. In their constructor, ask for a DarkWorld parameter darkworld and set `this.darkworld = darkworld;`
Then, in that if statement just call `darkworld.updateStats();`

Comment: Okay, so within another class - say, the BattleFrame - to fill the darkWorld object I've declared, how I do tell it I mean the DarkWorld object that has already been created (ie, the object created when I first executed the program)?

Comment: Perhaps add a get method to the original DarkWorld object which has a `return this;` line?

Comment: Ah, no, that didn't work because I can't use that line in a static method (such as `public static DarkWorld getDarkWorld()`)

Comment: As I said - pass it in the constructor

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean now. Sorry, still getting the hang of this. :)

Comment: If it helped you, do you mind checking that checkmark next to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest you do not do it this way, instead have the stats display screen listen
to the main player object. When the main player object has one of it's stats altered
then the stats screen can update itself.

```
...
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
...

public class User {

    private List<PropertyChangeListener> propertyListeners;

    ... add, and remove listener methods ...        


    public void setHitPoints(int newValue){
       PropertyChangeEvent event = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "hitPoints", myHitpoints, newValue);
       myHitpoints = newValue;
       for (PropertyChangeListener listener : propertyListeners){
          listener.propertyChange(event);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes, this is a much better solution.

Comment: Eclipse is giving me an error on this line:

`private List<PropertyChangeListener> propertyListeners;`

The error says "PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type". I haven't used PropertyChangeListener or PropertyChangeEvent before. Are these things I need to create in order to use? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: are you importing it? import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;